# Oracle SQL developer timestamp format not changing to 24

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm inserting a timestamp value using python into an oracle database

```
timestamp_v = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp_v)

cur = conn.cursor()
query = 'INSERT INTO all_machines_data(timestamp, hostname, ip_address, up_time, cpu_utilization, running_processes, total_memory, available_memory, used_memory, total_disk_capacity, free_disk_space, used_disk_space, network_requests_sent, network_requests_received) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14)'
values = (timestamp_v, system_info()[1], system_info()[3], str(system_info()[2]), cpu_info()[0], cpu_info()[1], memory_info()[0], memory_info()[1], memory_info()[2], disk_info()[0], disk_info()[1], disk_info()[2], network_info()[0], network_info()[1])
cur.execute(query,values)

conn.commit()
print("Data Sent!")

>> 04-Apr-2022 23:30:22
>> Data Sent!
```

My problem is in sql developer not accepting to show it in 24h format and always showing the 12h format

[image]

I tried every solution I found on the internet and still no luck1- tried setting the correct format I want in Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS : DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS

[image]

- Tried using the query

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

- Tried restarting sql developer/ stopping oracles services and still no luck
any help is apperciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your screenshot shows a column named `TIMESTAMP`. Is that a column in a table in which you inserted the values from your external source? If so, what is the data type of that column, and how do you display it (what query are you using)? For the data type, try `describe <table_name>` (use the actual table name) - often people are surprised to see that the data type is not what they thought it was.

Comment: Then, next thing to check (assuming for example that the data type is `date`) is what data was actually inserted in the table. You could do `select dump(timestamp) from table_name` to see the exact bytes saved on disk. Post an example here, even if you don't quite understand it; we'll help you decode it. It is possible that the value got changed somehow BEFORE it was saved in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @mathguy . Yes, I have a column I made called TIMESTAMP and its type is TIMESTAMP(6) as the describe <table_name> returned I use select * from <table_name> to display it like the screenshot above of the column TIMESTAMP. Running select dump(timestamp) from table_name is returning: Typ=180 Len=7: 120,122,4,5,3,1,51

Comment: that must be for a value you just added (the date is April 5, and the time is 2:00:50 in the morning). What do you get if you DUMP something with a time of 23:00:00 or similar? Like the values you were discussing in the original post?

Comment: How to read the "dump": From the first two bytes, subtract 100; that leaves 20 and 22. Those are the "century" (not really; the first two digits of the year) and the year within the "century". The year is 2022. Then 4 and 5 (the third and fourth byte) are the month and the day - that's how I know that date is April 5, not April 4. Then 3, 1, 51 are the hour, minute, second - all incremented by 1. So the time is 02:00:50 (in the morning); a time-of-day like 22:30:00 would be shown as 23:31:1.

Comment: Note though that whatever you put in the table should follow the same process as originally - create a timestamp in python, with a time-of-day in the afternoon or evening; then save it to Oracle through your same process, and look at the data in Oracle (with DUMP). I don't know python, to tell if what you are doing is right or not, but this small experiment will tell us where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Python code you are using to insert the value into the database, including how you are converting your `timestamp_v` string to an Oracle timestamp. As you appear to end up with an 11am value in the database (the dump output to confirm that would still be useful) the issue seems to be in the insert process. (Your Python and database time zone settings might also be relevant, but probably not.)

Comment: @mathguy I run again `select dump(timestamp)` and I'm getting Typ=180 Len=7: 120,122,4,5,8,22,30

Comment: @AlexPoole I just edited the post and included the code, I noticed that the problem might be in the strftime directives, I'm referring to [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/warehouse-management/22a/owmld/python-strftime-directives.html#python_strftime_directives) if I use `("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")` in which the 24h format is %H I'm getting an error **Failed to insert record into table ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12** , if I use `("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S")` with %I is for the 12h format, it's getting inserted no problems. note that my sql developer is always showing the 12H format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I use ("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S") in which the 24h format is %H I'm getting an error Failed to insert record into table ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12 ,

You are relying on implicit conversion of your string to a timestamp, which uses your session NLS settings. Note that is your session from Python, which is separate from your SQL Developer session - and they have different NLS settings.

Change your insert to expect a string with a 24-hour time; instead of the first bind being simply

```
query="... values(:1, ..."
values = (timestamp_v, ...
```

make it:

```
query="... values(to_timestamp(:1, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS`), ..."
values = (timestamp_v, ...
```

... which still replies on the month abbreviation being converted - implying your Python and Oracle sessions are using the same date language; you can specify the language on the Oracle side but... it would be better to use an unambiguous format like

```
timestamp_v = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
...
... values(to_timestamp(:1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`), ...
values = (timestamp_v, ...
```

But it would be even better to bind the actual timestamp value and not use a string at all. I don't know Python but perhaps something as simple as:

```
query="... values(:1, ..."
values = (datetime.utcnow(), ...
```

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146385/266304) suggests that is the case.)

It's much better to use the correct data type rather than converting to and from strings, whether that is implicit or explicit.

> if I use ("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S") with %I is for the 12h format, it's getting inserted no problems.

Yes, because you're now providing the hour as 11, not 23.

> note that my sql developer is always showing the 12H format

No, it's showing 24-hour format, your time is just actually 11 am.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem, converting the string to timestamp and inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMP         
----------------------
2022-04-04 20:27:11.35 
1526000
```

Comment: The OP seems to think his column is data type `date`; but even if it is timestamp with time zone, he has shown the format in SQL Developer. It does show `hh24` - yet the value is displayed in 12 hour format. So I don't see how your answer will help.