# Cx_Oracle using 'TO_DATE' in python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to call Oracle function within Python using cx_oracle

Oracle function:

```
function SetMessageInfo(  plogid                     number,
                          pmess_oper_status          number,
                          pmess_reason_code          number,
                          pmess_counter_measure_code number,
                          poper_trans_date           date) return number;
```

Python:

```
plogid = 215
pmess_oper_status = None
pmess_reason_code = 1
pmess_counter_measure_code = 1
now = datetime.datetime.now()

try:    
                result_end = curOracle.callfunc('PKG_IMPORT.setmessageinfo', int, [plogid, pmess_oper_status, pmess_reason_code, pmess_counter_measure_code, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')])
            except Exception as err:
                print('Can not execute setmessageinfo',err)
            else:
                print('Succesfully executed setmessageinfo')
```

and I get cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error.

**UPD:**
Solved. When using cx_Oracle call_func need to pass as parameter all variables, i.e. even those which are not mandatory by PL/SQL function.

Comment: You're missing `pmess_reason_code` in the list of arguments, so it will be trying to implicitly convert your formatted date string to a number, which would throw that error. (But you will also have a problem passing that formatted string as a date argument, unless your Oracle session's NLS settings match. [Pass the datetime, not a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146385/266304).)

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm sorry, it's my error while copying, actually pmess_reason_code is added as function parameter

Comment: If that is the case then what data types and values are those other arguments? Please edit your question to provide a [mre].